# How to make strace print addresses of string arguments instead of just their values?

Tags: linux, debugging, reverse-engineering, strace

I'm trying to use `strace` to understand how a binary program uses memory.

However, the default output of `strace`, in an attempt to be more user friendly, prints any `char *` buffers as the respective strings.

```
read(3, "Tell me, Muse, of that man of ma"..., 4096) = 270
```

Is there any way to tell `strace` to print the actual address of the string next to its contents?

If it's not possible to have both, printing only the address of the string instead of its truncated contents would also be ok.

Comment: I don't think that's the way strace(1) is meant to be used. You might want to take a look at ltrace and gdb instead.

Comment: Maybe it's not supported, but I don't see how what I describe is out of scope for strace. It already does the job but does not print the information in the format I need. I've already checked ltrace and it has the same behaviour (i.e. char * buffers are printed as strings). gdb is intented for interactive debugging which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download [the source of `strace`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/) and modify all these `tprintf("%s", ...)` to `tprintf("%p", ...)`, and build a local copy of `strace`.

Comment: Source modification is an option. I'm investigating this but it is a bit trickier than it seems.

Comment: Look forward to your share of your solution to this problem.

Comment: I made this patch for the purpose: https://gist.github.com/m000/9240954
It should be fairly easy to add a command line switch to turn this behaviour on or off. But it wouldn't worth the trouble unless the strace maintainers were interested to merge this to the trunk.

Comment: @m000 Great, your patch looks quite nice.

Answer (score 20):

-e raw=read should do what you want already. There should be no need for source modification.

broadway@creepspread:~% strace -e raw=read ls 2>&1|grep ^read
read(0x3, 0x7fff5ea52e78, 0x340)        = 0x340
read(0x3, 0x7fff5ea52e48, 0x340)        = 0x340
read(0x3, 0x7fff5ea52e18, 0x340)        = 0x340
read(0x3, 0x7fff5ea52de8, 0x340)        = 0x340
read(0x3, 0x7fff5ea52ca8, 0x340)        = 0x340
read(0x3, 0x7fff5ea52c48, 0x340)        = 0x340
read(0x3, 0x7fff5ea52c18, 0x340)        = 0x340
read(0x3, 0x7fef1433f000, 0x400)        = 0x136
read(0x3, 0x7fef1433f000, 0x400)        = 0

Comment: Nice to know this. Still, when debugging it is useful to know both what and where. By default strace only shows you what is written. With this option it only shows you where it is written. With the modifications made by my patch it shows you both: read(3, 0x9118000:"This is strace, a system call tr"..., 32768) = 592

Comment: -e raw=read -e read=all shows both undecoded data for read system call as well as a hex dump of what is read. The argument to -e read is a list of file descriptors, so you can filter it that way.